# SharePoint Search Crawl Property Issue 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

In SharePoint 2013 search crawl property is created automatically. But in my case I have created 5 new site column from 5 site column only 1 site column's crawl property is created in search service others are not created.

We can create manage property pro grammatically.  But if crawl property does not create in that case we can't create manage property.

Any one has idea why crawl property is not created automatically?

Comment: Did you do a fullcrawl?

Comment: Some times if values are not stored in Site Columns, then such behaviour is seen. Add values and run incremental crawl. It should work.